# View names of controls in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I feel a little foolish asking this question.  I have spent plenty of time searching and only found a crude work-around.  I have given this due diligence before posting.

For controls placed within a worksheet I cannot pull up the properties or even view the name to reference in code.  The work-around I came across is if you right-click on the control (listbox in this case) and choose assign macro.  It will suggest a macro name with the control name (e.g. ListBox13_change).  In the code I refer to this listbox as Sheet2.ListBox13, but getting an error message for missing object.

With ActiveX controls or controls within a userform I can view the properties.  I don't know why I am having trouble with this case.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the real name of the form control from the Immediate Window in the VBE by executing this line:

```
?Sheet2.Shapes(1).Name
```

Form controls are actually shapes in the object model.

The above assumes you have no other shapes on the worksheet.

**Of course** you can also see the name (and edit it) from the Name Box if the control is selected.

Once you have the name you can use  it in code like so:

```
MsgBox Sheet2.Shapes("List Box 1").Top
```